# PDF parsing library for C++/Windows

Tags: windows, library, pdf, c++

I need to create a C++ program which parse info from a PDF file. So, I guess, the first step is to find a good, easy-to-use library. I've already searched on google, but I only found stuff for Linux or outdated/not functioning libraries.

Can you recommend me a good free library ? I don't need many functions, I just need to extract info from a PDF file.

Comment: What kind of info are you looking to parse/extract from a PDF?

Comment: text strings, something like "Name: <name>; Address: <address>; etc ..."

Comment: Do you really need it to be C++? Couldn't it be in another language and output the information in another format?

Answer (score 1):

[PoDoFo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/podofo/) is a library to work with the PDF file format. The name comes from the first letter of PDF (Portable Document Format). A few tools to work with PDF files are already included in the PoDoFo package.

The PoDoFo library is a free, portable C++ library which includes classes to parse PDF files and modify their contents into memory. The changes can be written back to disk easily. The parser can also be used to extract information from a PDF file (for example the parser could be used in a PDF viewer). Besides parsing PoDoFo includes also very simple classes to create your own PDF files. All classes are documented so it is easy to start writing your own application using PoDoFo.

PoDoFo is written in C++ and the code was sucessfully compiled under Unix, Mac OS X and Windows.